# Extracting tags using select_one

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am trying to extract content within specific tags using CSS selector in Python from this page:
https://scenarieconomici.it/page/898/

Specifically, I am interesting in title, date, author, category and summary.
I have tried as follows:

```
    print(tag.select_one(".entry-title").text)
    print(tag.select_one("span.meta-time").text)
    print(tag.select_one("span.meta-author").text)
    print(tag.select_one("span.category-item").text)
    print(tag.find_next(class_="entry-content").text.strip())
```

Could you please tell me if they are right? I could provide you with the whole code I am using, if required.

Many thanks

---

After the Wasif's answer below, I changed my code but unfortunately it seems there is still a problem with tags:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import pandas as pd

def main(req, num):
    r = req.get("https://scenarieconomici.it/page/{}/".format(num))
    # r = req.get("https://www.imolaoggi.it/category/polit/page/{}/".format(num))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    #goal = [(x.time.text, x.h3.a.text, x.select_one("span.cat-links").get_text(strip=True), x.p.get_text(strip=True))
     #       for x in soup.select("div.site-content")]
    for tag in soup.select('div', class_='entry-blog'):
        print(tag.find('span',class_='entry-title'))
        print(tag.find('span',class_='meta-time'))
        print(tag.find('span',class_='meta-author'))
        print(tag.find('span',class_='category-item'))
        print(tag.find_next(class_='entry-content'))
    return tag.find('span',class_='entry-title'),tag.find('span',class_='meta-time'), tag.find('span',class_='meta-author'), tag.find('span',class_='category-item'), tag.find_next(class_='entry-content')

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as executor:
    with requests.Session() as req:
        # fs = [executor.submit(main, req, num) for num in range(1, 2937)]
        fs = [executor.submit(main, req, num) for num in range(1, 2)]
        allin = []
        for f in fs:
            allin.append(f.result())
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
            allin, columns=["Title", "Time", "Author", "Category", "Content"])
```

as I am getting only None values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from itertools import repeat
import re
import pandas as pd


def main(req, num):
    r = req.get("https://scenarieconomici.it/page/{}/".format(num))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    return [(
            x.select_one("h2.entry-title").text,
            x.select_one("span.meta-time").text,
            x.select_one("span.meta-author").a.text,
            x.select_one("span.category-item").a.text,
            x.select_one("div.entry-content").p.text
            )
            for x in soup.findAll("article", id=re.compile(r"post-\d+"))]


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
    with requests.Session() as req:
        fs = executor.map(main, repeat(req), range(1, 899))
        final = []
        [final.extend(f) for f in fs]
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
            final, columns=["Title", "Time", "Author", "Category", "Content"])
        print(df)
```

Output

```
                                                   Title              Time  ...         Category                                            Content
0      LA SOLUZIONE DEL TEAM BIDEN PER IL COVID: MORI...  11 Novembre 2020  ...       attualita'  Ezekiel Emanuel Biden ha gia fatto partire i s...
1      10 Procuratori Statali con Trump, contro la Pe...  11 Novembre 2020  ...       attualita'  I procuratori generali del Missouri, Alabama, ...
2      TAGLIARE L’IVA: rilanciare l’economia ed incre...  11 Novembre 2020  ...       attualita'  Ieri Salvini e Bagnai hanno presentato il pian...
3      Il Parlamento Europeo? Incrementa i vincoli su...  10 Novembre 2020  ...       attualita'  Lunedì in commissione ECON è  stato  discusso ...
4      Dove siete finiti, cari rigoristi dell’austeri...  10 Novembre 2020  ...  analisi e studi  Dove siete finiti, detrattori della spesa pubb...
...                                                  ...               ...  ...              ...                                                ...
17941     Analisi della CRISI attuale: la GUERRA incombe  12 Novembre 2011  ...    Uncategorized  10 domande e 10 rispostePerche’ gli spread tra...
17942  SEMPLICE CRISI FINANZIARIA O TERZA GUERRA MOND...    12 Luglio 2011  ...    Uncategorized  Intervista immaginaria a Frank (che spiega per...
17943  SLIDING DOORS: “SIAMO L’UNICO PAESE DEL MONDO ...    12 Giugno 2011  ...    Uncategorized  Spesso siamo portati a criticare, a lamentarci...
17944             L’origine del DEBITO PUBBLICO Italiano    12 Giugno 2011  ...    Uncategorized  Spesso ci si chiede la vera origine del nostro...
17945                              La caduta dei Giganti    12 Giugno 2011  ...    Uncategorized  Vorrei soffermarmi un’istante sui 3 paesi card...

[17946 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. can you explain why id=re.compile(r"post-\d+") is required?

Comment: @Math you welcome, glad to help. i used `re` to pickup the posts with `post-x` where x is digits. but you could just use `soup.select("article[id^='post-']")` if you not familiar with `regex`

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation. Really appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `.find()` instead:

```
print(tag.find('span',class_='your class'))
```

Comment: Thanks Wasif Hasan. I tried with it as well, but I think there is some problems with tags selection at this point. Could you please confirm tags and classes I have selected are the right ones?

Comment: Sorry, I will be offline for a few hours now, you can just open the URL in browser, right click on the elements and then click Inspect. And then you can get the tag classes

Comment: np, Wasif. Yes, this is what I have already done. I am using Chrome and Inspect to select tag classes